# Erro 401 com axios

Tags: javascript, react, loop, post, axios

Estou tentando fazer um POST em uma API desenvolvida por mim que esta na Azure.
O POST para realizar login funciona.
mas a essa altura estou tentando fazer um loop para realizar vários POST.

```
repayment.forEach(element => {
            const token = sessionStorage.getItem("@TOKEN")
            axios.post("https://repayment-api.azurewebsites.net/repayment", element ,{
                 headers: {
                    Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`
                }
            })
            .then((res) => {
                setRepayment([])
                return console.log(res) // chamar toast se der certo 
            }).catch(err => console.log(err))
        });
```

mas ao passar pelo loop o server me retorna um erro 401, sendo que todas as informações necessárias para realizar o POST já estão contidas no "element" e o token, que esta sendo atribuído pelo login ao localstorage "@TOKEN".
Ao testar no Insomnia tudo ocorre corretamente.

realizei um teste fazendo o login no insomnia e copiando o token e enviando ele diretamente no POST do axios, mas ainda continua retornando um erro 401.

obs: não é erro de CROS pós o mesmo já esta configurado, e se fosse eu não passaria da etapa de login.

Comment: cara, é o seguinte, na minha visão de acordo com o código que postou, supondo que fez tudo certo, e pelas descrições que deu, o item que está no seu localstorage o `"@TOKEN"` está expirado.

Comment: Por favor, esclareça seu problema ou forneça detalhes adicionais a fim de destacar exatamente o que você precisa. Da forma como está escrito atualmente é difícil dizer com exatidão o que você está perguntando.

Comment: @Danizavtz o token é armazenado quando o usuário efetua um login, a função que faz isso limpa o Localstorage e armazena o novo token.

Comment: @danizavtz talvez o problema seja esse `sessionStorage` na pergunta você deixa bem claro que está guardando no `localStorage`, então porque o uso do `sessionStorage`?

Comment: é verdade, não tinha percebido essa diferença sutil mas relevante, @William.

Comment: Opa, viu o comentário do @William, você está lendo o token do `sessionStorage`. Quando você afirma que está salvando ele no `localStorage`. São locais de armazenamentos distintos. Poste o código em que armazena o `"@token"`.

Comment: Você já verificou se o token expirou?